# VSCode Java Project - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException if I run the project at other drive except in Windows drive (Drive C)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I like to organize the code in other drive except Windows drive in case of Windows reinstallation. I test in both location. In Windows drive, the project can run properly, but in the other hand, project that in the drive D cannot run because it caused the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. I notice that if I no have any library in the project, the command in terminal is `'-cp' 'D:\งาน\Java\Project\MyApp\bin' 'com.winrecker.app.App"`. So the project can run properly without any error. After that, I copied the `.jar` library into `lib` folder and run again, the project has the same error as mentioned above.
Is there any way that I can disable vscode for making the `.argfile` that caused the error? I'm tried to created `.launch.json` in `.vscode` folder. Then add a configuration as follows

launch.json

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Launch Game",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "com.untitled.game.Game",
      "projectName": "Alien Hunter",
      "vmArgs": "-Djava.library.path=lib/lwjgl/native/windows",
      "shortenCommandLine": "none"
    }
  ]
}
```

settings.json

```
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": [
        "src",
        "lib",
        "res"
    ],
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar"
    ]
}
```

And run again, the project can at any drive other than Windows drive.
I'm so curious why `shortenCommandLine` and create the `.argfile` caused the error in project that not in Windows drive.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [official docs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug) said:

> shortenCommandLine - When the project has long classpath or big VM
> arguments, the command line to launch the program may exceed the
> maximum command line string limitation allowed by the OS. This
> configuration item provides multiple approaches to shorten the command
> line. Defaults to auto.
>
> - none - Launch the program with the standard command line 'java    options classname [args]'.
> - jarmanifest - Generate the classpath parameters to a temporary    classpath.jar file, and launch the program with the command line 'java -cp classpath.jar classname [args]'.
> - argfile - Generate the classpath parameters to a temporary argument    file, and launch the program with the command line 'java @argfile[args]'. This value only applies to Java 9 and higher.
> - auto - Automatically detect the command line length and determine    whether to shorten the command line via an appropriate approach.

Looks like the path of the folder in the D driver is longer then in the C Driver, so the Java extension automatically creates the `.argfile` file.

Comment: I​ tested a​ big​ project​ both​ of​ C​ Drive​ and​ D​ Drive, If​ not​ specify in​  `setting.json`,  the​ Java​ extension​ still​ create​ the​ `.argfile` file.

Comment: @Paweenwat Maneecha Have you configured `"java.jdt.ls.vmargs"` or your project has a long folder path?